# How is Paramiko segregating output and error message?

Tags: linux

If I execute `jdksjdkd` in terminal from one machine to another machine using paramiko I am getting `stderr.readlines()` as  `Command not found`.

Comment: That "command not found" is usually printed by the shell to its stderr. That's probably how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PATH environment variable indicates that where the commands resides. 
So in your case , since "`jdksjkdk`" is not found in the `$PATH` , it throws error on `STDERR` file descriptor and hence you are getting `stderr.readiness()` as Command not found

> > **Explanation:** There are 3 standard file descriptors, every running program in linux opens the following file descriptors
> >
> > 1. STDIN (0) => for standard input
> > 2. STDOUT(1) => for standard output
> > 3. STDERR (2) => for standard error
>
> So when the command was not found, the error was written to `STDERR` (
>   file desciptor => 2 ) , if it was successful, then output would had
>   been written to `STDOUT` ( file descriptor => 1 ) .  Since paramiko is
>   reading result from `STDERR` and not `STDOUT` , this is how it is
>   verifying it is error not output

Comment: I believed the above statement. but in one of my case I am getting stdout(output) as stderr message.
The data got swapped between this two. So that I raised this question.

Comment: Maybe then it must be checking the return status of your process to check if it failed or not